# Integrate (embed) Openfire-Server into another Java-Project

Tags: java, eclipse, git, ant, xmpp

I cloned the Openfire-Source from Git-Repository (https://github.com/igniterealtime/Openfire), set it up into Eclipse and did an Ant-Build of it.
Openfire is running with my prefered custom configuration and is connected to an MySQL-Database, which stores users, passwords... Launching the server from Eclipse works fine.

My goal is to start Openfire "invisible" from another Java-Project (JavaFX in my case). If possible, i want to merge both projects into only one.

The build Openfire project was added to classpath of my JavaFX-Application.

1) First i tried to instantiate Openfires Startup.jar in my existing JavaFX-Stage-Controller with

```
public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {

    initListener();
    initContents();

    org.jivesoftware.openfire.starter.ServerStarter.main(null); 

    ...

}
```

Like expected, the VM-parameters are missing:

```
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/C:/Users/knoop/Desktop/java/slf4j-1.7.13/slf4j-jdk14-1.7.13.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/C:/Users/knoop/Desktop/java/Openfire_git/build/lib/ant/slf4j-simple.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/C:/Users/knoop/Desktop/java/Openfire_git/build/lib/dist/slf4j-log4j12.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.slf4j.impl.JDK14LoggerFactory]
Jan 27, 2016 5:52:28 PM org.jivesoftware.util.Log warn
WARNUNG: Admin Lib Directory ../plugins/admin/webapp/WEB-INF/lib does not exist. Web admin console may not work.
Could not locate home
java.io.FileNotFoundException
    at org.jivesoftware.openfire.XMPPServer.locateOpenfire(XMPPServer.java:827)
    at org.jivesoftware.openfire.XMPPServer.initialize(XMPPServer.java:304)
    at org.jivesoftware.openfire.XMPPServer.start(XMPPServer.java:440)
    at org.jivesoftware.openfire.XMPPServer.<init>(XMPPServer.java:169)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.jivesoftware.openfire.starter.ServerStarter.start(ServerStarter.java:105)
    at org.jivesoftware.openfire.starter.ServerStarter.main(ServerStarter.java:56)
    at org.server_fx.GUI.controller.MainScreenController.initialize(MainScreenController.java:53)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(Unknown Source)
    at org.server_fx.GUI.controller.GUI_Shared.loadFXMLToStage(GUI_Shared.java:63)
    at org.server_fx.GUI.fxml.Manager.start(Manager.java:24)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$163(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$176(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$174(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$175(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$149(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Jan 27, 2016 5:52:28 PM org.jivesoftware.openfire.XMPPServer start
SCHWERWIEGEND: null
java.io.FileNotFoundException
    at org.jivesoftware.openfire.XMPPServer.locateOpenfire(XMPPServer.java:827)
    at org.jivesoftware.openfire.XMPPServer.initialize(XMPPServer.java:304)
    at org.jivesoftware.openfire.XMPPServer.start(XMPPServer.java:440)
    at org.jivesoftware.openfire.XMPPServer.<init>(XMPPServer.java:169)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.jivesoftware.openfire.starter.ServerStarter.start(ServerStarter.java:105)
    at org.jivesoftware.openfire.starter.ServerStarter.main(ServerStarter.java:56)
    at org.server_fx.GUI.controller.MainScreenController.initialize(MainScreenController.java:53)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(Unknown Source)
    at org.server_fx.GUI.controller.GUI_Shared.loadFXMLToStage(GUI_Shared.java:63)
    at org.server_fx.GUI.fxml.Manager.start(Manager.java:24)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$163(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$176(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$174(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$175(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$149(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

Jan 27, 2016 5:52:28 PM org.jivesoftware.util.LocaleUtils getLocalizedString
SCHWERWIEGEND: Can't find bundle for base name openfire_i18n, locale de_DE
Critical Error! The home directory has not been configured, 
which will prevent the application from working correctly.

startup.error
```

Which results in a missing Openfire-home-directory.

2) Openfire.bat contains specific parameters for launching the server (DopenfireHome="%OPENFIRE_HOME%").

So I tried:

```
public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {

    initListener();
    initContents();

    try {

        Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("java" -DopenfireHome=\"C:\\Users\\knoop\\Desktop\\java\\Openfire_git\\target\\openfire\" -jar C:\\Users\\knoop\\Desktop\\java\\Openfire_git\\target\\openfire\lib\startup.jar");

    } catch (IOException e) {   e.printStackTrace();    }

    ...

}
```

which results in nothing. No exception or else.

Is there another way to instantiate the OpenFire server from another Java-Project, or to "invisibly" launch the server in background with the correct launch parameters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok it works now.

JavaFX-Init:

```
    private void initContents() {

        System.setProperty("openfireHome", "C:/Users/knoop/Desktop/java/workspace/Openfire/target/openfire");
        System.setProperty("openfire.lib.dir", "C:/Users/knoop/Desktop/java/workspace/Openfire/target/openfire/lib");

        org.jivesoftware.openfire.starter.ServerStarter.main(null);

    }
```